# Error "FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service ..." while using Spring Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

Migrating from `Ribbon`, i am trying to use `spring cloud load balancer` but faced below error.

```
2021-01-06 00:42:10.251 ERROR 12948 --- [nio-8100-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [GET] to [http://currency-exchange-service/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR] [CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy#retrieveExchangeValue(String,String)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service currency-exchange-service]] with root cause

feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [GET] to [http://currency-exchange-service/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR] [CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy#retrieveExchangeValue(String,String)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service currency-exchange-service]
    at feign.FeignException.serverErrorStatus(FeignException.java:237) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:180) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.retrieveExchangeValue(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.springboot.microservices.currencyconversionservice.controller.CurrencyConversionController.convertCurrencyFeign(CurrencyConversionController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_261]
```

Please tell me what should i put in my Client Service - **currency-conversion-service's** `application.properties` file

`application.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=currency-conversion-service
server.port=8100
#currency-exchange-service.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:8000,http://localhost:8001
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=false
currency-exchange-service.ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.enabled=false
```

Full client service project **currency-conversion-service**, which is calling **currency-exchange-service**, can be accessed from https://github.com/AshishBharadwaj94/currency-conversion-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#simplediscoveryclient)

```
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.currency-exchange-service[0].uri=http://localhost:8080
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.currency-exchange-service[1].uri=http://localhost:8081
```

Comment: Meaning, I have to reformat list of servers in to above format and no way to provide list in single line? Currently I am using a ribbon and reading the list of severs from config sever parameter. I couldn't see any other option either...
`ribbon:
  listOfServers: ${app.main.config.external.hosts}`

Comment: This isn't Ribbon and doesn't have a compatible single line option

Comment: This works, but the whole idea is we would not need to configure these URL's manually when using Eureka along with Feign. Is there any other way to solve this issue apart from manually declaring the URL's

Comment: The original question didn't involve eureka, it used ribbon static configuration

Answer (score 0):

pay attention that your service name is:
spring.application.name=currency-conversion-service

and make sure that the @FeignClient annotation in proxy interface points to it
@FeignClient(name="currency-exchange-service")

Comment: Please provide a more detailed and easier-to-understand explanation in your answer. Use the edit function to improve it. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).